# IOS: advertising in app iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, iad, ads

In my app I want to insert advertising; I search on google and many people use only a service to their app, at the example only iAd or only adMob ecc..
Other people say that is better insert in an app more services for advertising; for example iAd and adMob (50% and 50%) and when iAd not respond adMob can replace iAd service.
But what are the benefits of having 2 or 3 services in addition to iAd to serve advertisements in a specific app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experience & reading, iAd tends to have the best pay out, *but* it doesn't have a 100% fill rate. That means only *some* of the time that your app requests an ad will it actually get one. Also, iAd isn't available in all countries (according to the site, you're only supposed to serve iAd ads in U.S., Canada, Mexico, U.K., France, Germany, Italy, Spain, Australia, New Zealand and Japan, as of April 4, 2013).

Using multiple networks would allow you to fall back to another network for those situations, which will help improve your revenue (because you'll nearly always have an ad). AdWhirl is a popular framework that helps you automate and manage the ratios and ordering of networks used in your app.

As for best, that's always harder to specify. Different people have had different combinations work better for them. Likely falling back will result in more revenue than a single network, but it would definitely be more work to set up and manage than a single network. From what I've read, iAd with AdMob fallback is probably viewed as the most profitable configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at MoPub and Burstly, they should have you a lot of time and possibly some headaches.  They will do Admob, iAds and quite a few others, some even through API's so you won't need to update future SDKs for those ad networks individually.

Also, I know a lot of people suggest Adwhirl but Google doesn't support it any longer.  Instead they moved the mediation into the Admob SDK and have improved the functionality.  It will do iAds as well.